# Specific value variables for each threading

Tags: python, selenium

I need for each of thread specific value for variable.

```
def login():
    driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login.email').send_keys(mail)
t1 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t2 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t3 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t4 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t5 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t6 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t7 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t8 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t9 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
t10 = threading.Thread(target=login, mail="")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def login(x):
   driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login.email').send_keys(x)
thread_list = []
for x in range(10):
   thread = threading.Thread(target=login, args=(x))
   thread_list.append(thread)
for thread in thread_list:
   thread.start()
   thread.join()
```

You can for loop and then thread with an args.